# Cross Cutting Direct Import Library into Use Case

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, joi, clean-architecture

I'm using a nodejs and practicing clean-architecture. This is probably a noob question but Is it ok to cross cut import a library (bcrypt, Joi) directly in the use-case? since that's where the validations are happening. Or is that a bad practice since it's the inner circle? Do i have to make something like a helper and inject them into the use-case? If yes, in what layer do i create that?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking all external frameworks and libraries have to be kept in the outer most circle. The inner circles can use such libraries using inversion of control, means you define an interface in the inner circle and implement it in the outer circle.

Having that said, I am usually a bit more pragmatic in my own projects. For a more detailed discussion of that topic pls see my blog post: http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Frameworks/